# Push Notification failed to register in remote server - MFP 8.0

Tags: cordova, push-notification, mfp

I have created sample application for Push Notification in MFP 8.0, I have installed mfpdev-cli and mfpdevkit, so i have my MFP 8.0 local server running in my machine.

Below steps are following for registering the device

1. Created app and added `cordova plugin mfp-push` and added android platform
2. Registered the app in mfp server using `mfpdev app register`
3. Set up API Key and Sender ID in mfp console
4. Added `push.mobileclient` scope mapping in mfp console under Security tab
5. Added necessary code for registering in MFP app
6. run the command : `mfpdev app pull`
7. run the command : `mfpdev app push`

*Connected to same wifi in android real device and machine, everything works fine app is successfully launching and device is registered.*

Local Server Details:

1. MFP version: 8.0.0.00-20170426-082318
2. MFPF runtime version: 8.0.2017021701
3. Liberty, version:8.5.5.8

But when I register the same app in remote MFP server(Installed on top of Liberty, MFPServer version is 8.0.0.00-20171025-0319) running in remote location, device registration failed with below message.

> "com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.push.api.MFPPushException:
>   Response: Status=404, Text: Error 404: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 404
>   , Error Message: Not Found"

**Snippet for Register Device:**

```
function registerDevice() {
    WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken("push.mobileclient").then(
        MFPPush.registerDevice(
            null,
            function(successResponse) {
                alert("Successfully registered");
            },
            function(failureResponse) {
                alert("Failed to register");
               alert("Failed to register device:" + JSON.stringify(failureResponse));
            }
        )
    );
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this error?